# Falha na execução do setInterval

Tags: javascript

```
if(inputUser.value == '' || inputPass.value == ''){
    setInterval(changeColor("blue"), 3000);
    alert('Tudo em branco');
}
function changeColor(cor){
    var prm = "1px solid "+cor;
    inputUser.style.border = prm;
}
```

Quando insiro um parâmetro na função `changeColor`, o `setInterval` não se comporta da maneira esperada, não respeitando os 3 segundos. Porque isso acontece?

Comment: Se houve uma resposta que resolva o problema aqui também podes marcar como aceite :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tens de ter em conta 3 conceitos diferentes:

- declarar uma função
- invocar a função (pode dizer-se "correr" ou "chamar" a função também)
- passar por referência

#### Declarar a função

Quando declaras uma função estás a defenir a mesma:

```
function teste(nome){
    nome = nome || '';
    return 'Olá ' + nome + ', hoje está um lindo dia!';
}
```

Neste momento não estás a correr a função, somente a dizer como ela é feita.

#### Invocar a função

Existem maneiras diferentes de invocar a função, a mais comum é

```
var saudacao = teste('João');
```

Os parenteses são a "ordem" para correr a função. Dessa maneira passas um argumento à função, ela corre o código que foi defenido e retorna uma *string* `"Olá João, hoje está um lindo dia!"`. A função é "consumida" e deixa no seu lugar a *string*. Ou seja a variável `saudacao` vai receber o valor da *string*.

Se a função não tiver `return` ela vai retornar `undefined`.

(Isto é o que estás a fazer no setInterval! a correr a função e a passar `undefined` para o setInterval);

#### Passar por referência

Podes passar uma função por referência. Ou seja indicar o nome dela, sem correr a mesma. Por exemplo, quuando queres executar uma função num setInterval, ou por oscultadorer de eventos diferêntes:

```
window.addEventListener('mousedown', minhaFn);
window.addEventListener('touchstart', minhaFn);
```

Desta maneira ambos os eventos usam a mesma função.

#### O problema no teu código:

O teu problema é que estás a invocar uma função que é consumida imediatamente antes de ser usas no `setInterval`. A função é consumida e , porque não tem return` o que acontece é

```
setInterval(undefined, 3000);
```

O que devias fazer:

```
setInterval(changeColor, 3000);
```

ou, passando uma declaração no momento:

```
setInterval(function(){
    var prm = "1px solid "+cor;
    inputUser.style.border = prm;
}, 3000);
```

Porém como estás a ver há um problema no código. Não passar a côr que precisas. Podes resolver isso com uma gambiarra (http://jsfiddle.net/k8gjre09/):

```
setInterval(changeColor.bind("blue"), 3000);
function changeColor() {
    var prm = "1px solid " + this;
    alert(prm);
}
```

Quando usas `.bind('blue')` estás a defenir o valor do `this` dentro da função.

Podes usar assim:

```
setInterval(function() {
    changeColor('blue');
}, 3000);
```

que corre a função a cada 3 segundos.

Mas o que devias fazer, uma vez que é sempre  mesma côr, é mudar o código para mudar de côr passando o nome da côr de outra maneira.

Answer (score 2):

Da forma colocada ele está chamando a função diretamente, o correto é:

```
setInterval(function() {
    changeColor("blue")
}, 3000);
```