# JQuery - Laço for dentro de uma DIV

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor, foreach

Galera, bom dia.

Simples:

Estou dando um For numa div:

```
<div class="Laço">
   <div class="ItemLaco"></div>
   <div class="ItemLaco"></div>
   <div class="ItemLaco"></div>
</div>
```

Agora preciso dar um For e que ele dinamicamente deixe o atual do laço visivel e o anterior invisivel! é possivel?

```
<script>
$(function () {
    this.class
    setInterval($(".ItemLaco").each(function (index, element) {
        alert(element);
    }),5000);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

O teu código tem alguns problemas mas imagino que queres fazer um efeito tipo *slideshow*, a mudar de div.

Podes fazer isso assim:

```
$(function () {
    var divs = $(".ItemLaco");
    var mostra = 0;

    function slide() {
        mostra++;
        if (mostra == divs.length) mostra = 0;
        divs.removeClass('mostrar');
        divs.eq(mostra).addClass('mostrar');
    }

    setInterval(slide, 2000);
});
```

#### jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Lwyo427a/

O `this.class` que tens não faz sentido, não percebo o que querias fazer com ele e por isso não posso corrigir nada.

No `setInterval` deves dar uma olhada [a esta pergunta/resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/69220/129), é o mesmo problema, ou seja tens de passar uma função como argumento para o `setInterval` usar/chamar de x em x tempo.

Depois tens `$(".ItemLaco").each`, não fica muito claro o que queres fazer mas no jQuery métodos aplicados a coleções de elementos são aplicados a todos. Por exemplo como eu usei em cima `ivs.removeClass('mostrar');` remove a classe de CSS a todos os elemento dessa coleção, mesmo que alguns não a tenham.

Usei classes de CSS para mostrar e esconder:

```
.ItemLaco {
    display: none;
}
.mostrar {
    display: block;
}
```

pois é melhor assim, mais limpo e tudo está no CSS.